# Caching mysql table for performance

Tags: mysql, performance, caching

In my page, I have multiple queries to fetch data from same table with different scenarios. These multiple queries give me performance issues. So I am trying to cache the table and then query that with different scenarios and in this way I don't need to hit the database all the time.

But, I don't know how to cache the table and query from it.

Can anyone help?

Is there any other way to improve the performance?

Comment: How much data is in the table? How much data is in the database as a whole? How much physical RAM do you have?

Comment: Most of what a DBMS is to cache file data and query data. Adding more caching tiers might be a solution but only after you've exhausted all the other avenues.

Answer (score 0):

Caching the table is easy: `select * from myTable`, and read the data into an array. You'll then have to search it yourself in your choice of language. For a small table and simple queries this could be faster. For a large table you could run into memory problems, and complex queries will become more difficult.

There are many potential ways to improve performance. Adding indexes to appropriate columns can make a world of difference, as can the exact order in which you perform queries and subqueries. Without any idea of the schema you're using, or the the queries you're applying it's impossible to say more.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- If you have considerably more physical RAM than the size of your databases, set the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable to a value larger than your database. InnoDB automatically caches tables in RAM until they change.
- If you have considerably more RAM than the size of the *table* you're interested in but don't want to rely on InnoDB's cache, try to use the MEMORY storage engine

MEMORY tables exist only in RAM so they're fast; they don't persist, but if you just want a cached version with that in mind, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE cachedcopy LIKE table;
ALTER TABLE cachedcopy ENGINE=MEMORY;
INSERT INTO cachedcopy SELECT * FROM table;
```

If your table is larger than available RAM (or you can't dedicate that memory to it), you'll have to use other techniques like creating indexes or trimming the data processed by each of your queries.